# Copied project still uses wrong folder

Tags: java, eclipse

How do I clone a workspace? I've tried copying its files from one folder to another  but when using this Eclipse just opens the old folders. For easier understanding, I'll refer to the old folders as folder1 and the new one as folder2. I copy my workspace from folder1 to folder2. Using Eclipse, I select folder2 but all of the files are still grabbed from folder1.

If I try copying it, making a new folder and opening the project and refactoring it to the new folder, it just fails with the very undescriptive error that there was a problem moving the files. Without actually telling me what the problem is. The solution was to copy the workspace folder, and import the project using general>existing projects into workspace, but this failed too. I tried doing the same to an empty folder but this just linked the old folder to the new one instead of cloning them.

Tried looking in the Eclipse .metadata folder with no luck, even after changing the files I found that had the old directory it bizarrely doesn't open the new folders! I renamed the parts that point to /folder1 to point to /folder2, but somehow it still opens folder1 for everything when I select folder2. I've wasted nearly two hours stumped, digging into it with no dice and I'm turning to this community hoping to get some help.

**Yes, I've Googled it**, very few results actually helped, with the only one fitting my situation not working. I NEED to clone this, starting from scratch is simply not an option.

Comment: Try creating a new project, and copying each file over to the new project, one at a time.  Check to make sure that all your imports point to the new project and not the old project.

Answer (score 0):

To clone a workspace:

1. Create a new workspace via ***File > Switch Workspace > Other...*** (this dialog offers also the option to copy your settings)
2. In the new workspace import the projects via ***File > Import...: General > Import Existing Projects into Workspace*** and make sure the checkbox ***Copy projects into workspace*** is checked

When the projects are located at different places or for transfer, you can also do ***File > Export...: General > Archive File*** first and then import the projects from that archive file.

Please note, the `.metadata` folder is not intended to be edited, moved or deleted.

Comment: I'm trying to mark this as an answer but for some reason it's not letting me.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way to solve this is as follows:

- delete the project(s), but **don't check** "[ ] delete project content on disk"
- then simply import the project(s) back (use "import existing maven project" if appropriate)

The project path is now updated.

If you are afraid of losing your files, just make a safe copy of your workspace before in some other directory.